# Error in Rcpp package and Linux GLIBCXX version compatability

Tags: r, linux

```
Error in `geom_point()`:
! Problem while converting geom to grob.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `dyn.load()`:
! unable to load shared object '/home/lab_anjohnson/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so':
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /home/lab_anjohnson/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so)
```

I tried downloading earlier version of Rcpp but the code is still not working. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to upgrade all the stuffs:

#### Update R and Rcpp:

Make sure you have the latest version of R and Rcpp:

```
update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)
install.packages("Rcpp")
```

#### Update or install system libraries:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade libstdc++6
```

#### Reinstall Rcpp:

```
remove.packages("Rcpp")
install.packages("Rcpp")
```

At least, check Library Paths running:
`.libPaths()`

Make also sure you not have multiple R installations.

Comment: I had an earlier error with another package "farver". When I downgraded the package, the error changed. 
But I did try updating and installing Rcpp now and I am still having the same issue.
I think since R is not up to date, since the latest version of R is not compatible with my Linux version, could be the issue.

Comment: This answer assumes OP is on a Debian, Ubuntu or derived system which was not stated in the question.

Comment: Yes it is performed on Debian.